# Rspec does not execute a "before_destroy" callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

In my book model, I have a "before_destroy" callback (with a potentially ugly method) as follows:

```
  before_destroy :destroy_fallback
  private

  def destroy_fallback
    unless self.fallback?
      format_fallback = BookFormat.find_by(fallback: true)
      Book.where(book_format_id: self.id).update(book_format_id: format_fallback.id)
    else
      errors.add(:base, :undestroyable)
      throw :abort
    end
  end
```

However when I test that this really happens, it doesn't seem to. This spec here results in an error (saying that the two id's are not the same):
require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe BookFormat, type: :model do
  before(:all) do
    @book = create(:hobbit)
    @book_format_default = create(:not_defined)
  end

  it 'should reassign to the fallback book_format if their book_format is deleted' do
    format = @book.book_format
    format.destroy
    expect(@book.book_format.id).to eq(@book_format_default.id)
  end
end
```

Looks like the destroy_fallback is never executed, i.e. the before_destroy callback is not used? In dev, when I do this via website - everything seems to works as desired.

Comment: you probably need to reload the `@book.book_format` object (and maybe the `@book` object too) in the spec... so `expect(@book.reload.book_format.reload.id).to... etc.`

Comment: put a `puts` statement in the callback to see if it's actually called, it may be called but the test is not confirming that. I'm thinking it must be called since it's working on the web page.

Comment: that was it - a simple @book.reload.book_format.id did the trick :) thanks.

Comment: It's hard to find answers in the comments, @Les or tkhobbes, can you post an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(upon request promoting my comment to an answer)

Since your destroy callback *is* being called on the web request, the problem lies in the Rspec code...

You need to reload the `@book` model in the `expect` statement, so:

`expect(@book.reload.book_format.id).to... etc.`

Answer (score 0):

Might just be copy-paste error, but you don't seem to have a `destroy_fallback` method in your model.

Make sure you're actually defining a method:

```rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
 before_destroy :destroy_fallback

  ...

  private
  
  def destroy_fallback
    unless self.fallback?
      format_fallback = BookFormat.find_by(fallback: true)
      Book.where(book_format_id: self.id).update(book_format_id: format_fallback.id)
    else
      errors.add(:base, :undestroyable)
      throw :abort
    end
  end
end
```

And, I find `unless - else` to be really hard to reason about.

```rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
 before_destroy :destroy_fallback

  ...

  private
  
  def destroy_fallback
    if self.fallback?
      errors.add(:base, :undestroyable)
      throw :abort
    else
      format_fallback = BookFormat.find_by(fallback: true)
      Book.where(book_format_id: self.id).update(book_format_id: format_fallback.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. The first observation relates to a copy/paste error of mine :). The second is of course true - that's what happens if you are in programming flow.

Comment: If this didn't fix it, can you update your question with the actual code?

Comment: the above answer from Les fixed it - I needed to reload the @book in the spec. But I also corrected the code.